# Question about jQuery and Bind

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to combine bind and dragable

```
$(".qq-upload-success").draggable({//functions});
```

have some one a solution?

I load this class with ajax. So this function doesn't work, so I have to bind() or live() this action to this class.

```
$(".qq-upload-success").bind("draggable", function()    {
        $.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var txta = $("textarea#kapiteltext");
            $("div#pseudodroppable").css({
                position:"absolute",
                top:txta.position().top,
                left:txta.position().left,
                width:txta.width(),
                height:txta.height()
            }).droppable(options).show();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("div#pseudodroppable").droppable('destroy').hide();
        }
        });
    });
```

or

```
$(".qq-upload-success").bind("drag", draggable({
        helper:'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var txta = $("textarea#kapiteltext");
            $("div#pseudodroppable").css({
                position:"absolute",
                top:txta.position().top,
                left:txta.position().left,
                width:txta.width(),
                height:txta.height()
            }).droppable(options).show();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("div#pseudodroppable").droppable('destroy').hide();
        }
    }));
```

thank you!

Comment: bind what event exactly?

Comment: bind draggable() to this class. This class isn't in DOM on load

Comment: You need to provide more details about your question and what you're trying to do.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/), you seem to be doing things correctly.  How are you applying the `qq-upload-success` class?  You need to provide this info in your question.

Comment: i add some information, i just try to bind() some function to this class.

Comment: yes, but this class isn't in DOM on load.... so it doen't works

Comment: I think you're looking for [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: yes, but how to combine it????

Comment: Your request isn't making sense. Are you saying how to dynamically make an element a draggable element using something like `.live()` or `.delegate()`?

Comment: i add some code, maybe it makes my problem clear

Comment: Why don't you add the draggable event handler when you add the new markup?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/h6qVT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to add non-event things (e.g. draggable) for all elements created in the future.

You need to create it when the element exists, e.g. by using `$('.foo:not(.ui-draggable)').draggable(...)` whenever such an element gets added.